# Filling a UIScrollView with content programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

There has to be a better way to fill a `UIScrollView` with `UILabel`, and `UIImageView` and other content without having to define `CGRectMake` with a start position. Is there such a thing as a stacking view? Im assuming not really, but what is the proper way of adding content dynamically.

Heres what Im doing currently:

```
func configureView() {
    self.addHeaderImage()

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var missionStatement: UILabel!
    var missionStatementText: UILabel!
    var history: UILabel!
    var historyText: UILabel!

    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, headerImage.bounds.height, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
    scrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height * 2)
    scrollView!.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    missionStatement = UILabel()
    missionStatement!.frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, headerImage.bounds.width - 20, 30)
    missionStatement!.text = "Our Mission Statement"
    missionStatement!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 22.0)
    scrollView.addSubview(missionStatement)

    missionStatementText = UILabel()
    missionStatementText!.frame = CGRectMake(10, missionStatement.frame.height, headerImage.bounds.width - 20, 100)
    missionStatementText!.text = "Covenant United Methodist Church, as a companionate community, serves people through the sharing, caring, and reaching out in the name of Jesus Christ."
    missionStatementText!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 17.0)
    missionStatementText!.numberOfLines = 0
    scrollView.addSubview(missionStatementText)

    history = UILabel()
    // By the time Im done adding things to this 1 view, Its going to be an insane addition problem to find the starting y of the rectangle
    history!.frame = CGRectMake(0, missionStatement.frame.height, 0, 0)
}
```

Comment: ever heard of a `UITableView`? You know the magical thing which is inherited from `UIScrollView` and allows you to fill it with content on run time without having to bother about setting frames yourself?

Comment: I have actually heard of such a thing. I however did not think it would be a viable candidate for what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: While it is true that you should not bother yourself with that if you want to show only a limited number of objects, but the thing is, that is the only way you don't have to bother with frames. It will be easier to create Cells programmatically than calculating frames for each and every label.A question though, why can't you create it in the IB?

Comment: @NSNoob Im adding a `UIImageView` in code based upon device size. I know adding from code is not the best way, but I feel Id learn more by doing it this way rather than all in IB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension to UIView

```
extension UIView {

    func addSubviewAtBottomOfAllSubviews(view:UIView){
        var maxY = CGFloat(0)
        for subview in self.subviews{
            if maxY < subview.frame.maxY{
                maxY = subview.frame.maxY
            }
        }

        view.frame.origin.y = maxY
        self.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

And also write func to resize Scroll content view, so make it scrollable if the views highet is bigger than the scroll view

```
extension UIScrollView{
    func resizeContentSize(){

        var contentRect = CGRectZero;
        for view in self.subviews{
            contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, (view ).frame);
        }

        self.contentSize = contentRect.size;

    }
}
```

use:

```
scrollView.addSubviewAtBottomOfAllSubviews(textLabel)
scrollView.addSubviewAtBottomOfAllSubviews(anotherView)
scrollView.resizeContentSize()
```

Comment: Im getting errors when copying over the UIView extension. 1) Binary operator < cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGPoint' and 'CGFloat'  2) Cannot assign value of type 'CGFloat' to type 'CGPoint' 3) Cannot assign value of type 'CGPoint' to type 'CGFloat'

Comment: @hightekjonathan sorry, fixed :)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't scroll any longer. No errors are thrown, and no warnings either. it just doesn't scroll when the content expands past the bottom page

Answer (score 1):

Improvements and extension of @Daniel Krom answer:

- now the view can be added on before or after the pre-existing subviews
- code improved

```
fileprivate extension UIView {

    enum SubviewPosition {
        case Top
        case Bottom
    }

    func addSubview(_ newView :UIView, relativeToOtherSubviewsAt position: SubviewPosition) {
        newView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(0)
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if position == .Top {
            self.addSubview(newView)
            for subview in self.subviews {
                subview.frame.origin.y += newView.frame.size.height
            }
        } else if position == .Bottom {
            //finding last subview
            var lastSubview = newView
            for subview in self.subviews {
                if subview.frame.maxY > lastSubview.frame.maxY {
                    lastSubview = subview
                    newView.frame.origin.y = subview.frame.maxY
                }
            }
            self.addSubview(newView)
            if lastSubview != newView {
                newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:lastSubview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate extension UIScrollView {

    func updateContentSize() {
        let contentRect: CGRect = subviews.reduce(into: .zero) { rect, view in
            rect = rect.union(view.frame)
        }
        contentSize = contentRect.size
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
scrollView.addSubview(customView, relativeToOtherSubviewsAt: .Top)
scrollView.addSubview(customView, relativeToOtherSubviewsAt: .Bottom)
```